# Does this Haskell program provide an example of "Theorems for free!"?

Tags: haskell

With respect **Listing 1**, it is required that the type level axiom

```
(t a) = (t (getUI(t a)))
```

should  derivable as a theorem for every specific type class instance.

Does the compilation of the `test` function prove the type level axiom holds for the particular types in the program? Does the compilation provide an example of [Theorems for free!](https://people.mpi-sws.org/~dreyer/tor/papers/wadler.pdf)?

**Listing 1**

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
data Continuant a = Continuant a  deriving (Show,Eq)

class UI a where

instance UI Int where

class Category t a where
   getUI :: (UI a) => (t a) -> a

 instance Category Continuant Int where
    getUI (Continuant a) = a

 -- axiom (t a) = (t (getUI(t a))) holds for given types?
 test :: Int -> Bool
 test x =  (Continuant x) == (Continuant (getUI (Continuant x)))
```

**Additional Context**

The code is based on a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/305430663_Ontologies_of_Dynamical_Systems_and_Verifiable_Ontology-Based_Computation_Towards_a_Haskell-Based_Implementation_of_Referent_Tracking) where it is stated:

> For all implementations of getUI one may require that the axiom  (t a)
>   = (t (getUI (t a))) holds. This must be proven to hold for every specific type class instance declaration. For finite types this can be
>   done by a program that enumerates all possibilities. For infinite
>   types this must be done manually via proofs by induction.

**Listing 1** was my attempt at a proof. In the light of Solution 1, perhaps I mistakenly thought this required [Theorems for free!](https://people.mpi-sws.org/~dreyer/tor/papers/wadler.pdf)

Comment: I think "how would I go about proving this" is a pretty different question -- and one that seems like it would be roughly welcome here on SO. Feel free to open a separate question. You might like to have a Google for "equational reasoning" (or perhaps "equational reasoning Haskell") first to see if reading a bit about that gives you enough hints to make progress yourself.

Comment: @Daniel I have asked the [follow-on question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54260109/how-could-i-prove-this-type-level-haskell-theorem) suggested.

Answer (score 6):

No, the fact that it's a class gives you far too much leeway for the type alone to guarantee that axiom. For example, the following alternate instance typechecks but violates your axiom:

```
instance Category Continuant Int where
    getUI _ = 42
```

(Being completely explicit, our adversary could choose for example `t=Continuant` and `a=6*9` to violate the axiom.) This abuses the fact that the class instantiator gets to choose the contained type. We can remove that ability by removing that argument to the class:

```
class Category t where
    getUI :: UI a => t a -> a
```

Alas, even this is not enough. We can write

```
data Pair a = Pair a a
```

and then the free theorem tells us that for `instance Category Pair`, we must write one of the following two definitions:

```
getUI (Pair x y) = x
-- OR
getUI (Pair x y) = y
```

Whichever we choose, our adversary can choose a `t` which shows us that our axiom is wrong.

```
Our choice                 Adversary's choice
getUI (Pair x y) = x       t y = Pair 42 y; a = 6*9
getUI (Pair x y) = y       t x = Pair x 42; a = 6*9
```

Okay, this abuses the fact that the class instantiator gets to choose `t`. What if we removed that ability...?

```
class Category where
    getUI :: UI a => t a -> a
```

This restricts the instantiator of `Category` quite a lot. Too much, in fact: `getUI` can't be implemented except as an infinite loop or the like.

I suspect it will be very difficult to encode the axiom you wish for as a type which can only be inhabited by things that satisfy it.

Comment: Thanks. Does the compilation prove anything at type level?

Comment: @PatrickBrowne Sure, lots of things! For example, you prove that `getUI` will never be passed an `Int`; you prove that, in the particular instance you wrote, the `a` will never be a `String` (this and the last are just "type correctness" theorems); if you wrote an `instance Category F a` for some specific type `F` but unconstrained type `a` you would prove roughly `t . getUI = getUI . fmap t` (as a free theorem).