# How could I prove this type level Haskell theorem?

Tags: haskell, proof

With respect to **Listing 1**, how would I go about proving the type level axiom

`(t a) = (t (getUI (t a)))`

holds?

**Listing 1**

```
    data Continuant a = Continuant a  deriving (Show,Eq)
        
    class UI a where -- ...
          
    instance UI Int where -- ...
        
    class Category t  where
      getUI :: (UI a) => (t a) -> a

   instance Category Continuant where
     getUI (Continuant a) = a
        
     -- Does axiom (t a) = (t (getUI(t a))) holds for given types?
     test :: Int -> Bool
     test x =  (Continuant x) == (Continuant (getUI (Continuant x)))
```

The code is based on a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/305430663_Ontologies_of_Dynamical_Systems_and_Verifiable_Ontology-Based_Computation_Towards_a_Haskell-Based_Implementation_of_Referent_Tracking) where it is stated:

> For all implementations of getUI one may require that the axiom  (t a)
> = (t (getUI (t a))) holds. This must be proven to hold for every specific type class instance declaration. For finite types this can be
> done by a program that enumerates all possibilities. For infinite
> types this must be done manually via proofs by induction.

My current intuition is that the `test` function in some way satisfies the axiom, but I do not think that it amounts to a proof.

This question follows on from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54253762/does-this-haskell-program-provide-an-example-of-theorems-for-free).

Comment: What is the `UI` class for? It has no methods, no constraints, and no functional dependencies. That would seem to make it quite useless.

Comment: @ dfeuer. UI is a class for unique identifiers. The code has been simplified to focus on the proof. So, in the context of the code the class just as a constraint on the type variables .

Comment: Ah... When I'm writing an example like that, I'll usually use an ellipsis to indicate that there's something in the body. `class UI a where ...`, `instance UI Int where ...`.

Answer (score 3):

To prove this, just start with one side of the equation and rewrite until you get to the other side.  I like to start with the more complicated side.

```
when x :: Int,

Continuant (getUI (Continuant x))
    --      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    -- by definition of getUI in Category Continuant Int
    = Continuant x
```

That was easy!  This does count as a proof (mind, not a formally verified one -- Haskell is not powerful enough to express term-level proofs.  But it's so trivial it wouldn't be worth the boilerplate in agda.).

I was a bit bewildered by the phrasing of this axiom, since it seems to be mixing up types and terms quite a lot.  Skimming the paper, it seems like this is only intended to work for simple single-constructor `newtype`s, thus this mixing is justified (still odd).  Anyway, it seems like the paper doesn't have the `Category` class parameterized on `a`: i.e. instead of

```
class Category t a where ...
```

it would be

```
class Category t where ...
```

which makes more sense to me, that the class describes polymorphic wrappers, rather than a possibly different description of how it wraps each individual type (especially since it appears that the axiom requires the implementation to be the same no matter what `a` you pick!).

Comment: Is the compilation or execution of `test` in any sense a proof of the theorem for specific types? –

Comment: No, it's a test case, which still provides a bit of assurance and is valuable, just not what "proof" means.  Of course if `test` ever returned false then you would have a proof that the property is false (because if it's false for one example, then it's not true for every example)